# EWS check if meeting is private

Tags: exchangewebservices

I'm curious if there is a way using the Exchange Web Services to determine if a meeting is flagged as private or not.

I'm setting up an app to display the current meeting for our various conference rooms.  The thing is, if a meeting is flagged as Private (the same way you flag a meeting as Important or Low Importance), I don't want to display any info about the meeting, just something generic.

I'm using ExchangeServiceBinding.GetUserAvailability of the meeting room.

I assumed that's what the CalendarEventDetails.isPrivate flag was for, but that seems to always be returned as true.

Does anyone know how I can access this flag?

Comment: After monkeying around with it and talking with the guys running the exchange server, we found a flag set on the exchange server called RemovePrivateProperty was set to true.  Flipping this to false caused the CalendarEventDetails.isPrivate flag to start behaving as expected.